# GCP Terraform Error waiting for disk to attach: The disk resource disk resource is already in use

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am able to create instances and volumes in GCP using terraform. But when I snapshot the volumes I get an error and the disk won't attach:

```
Error: Error waiting for disk to attach: The disk resource 'projects/btgcp-iaas-dev/zones/us-east1-d/disks/dev-sql-td-data-disk' is already being used by 'projects/btgcp-iaas-dev/global/snapshots/dev-sql-td-data-disk-volume-snapshot'


  on main.tf line 83, in resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "datadiskattach":
  83: resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "datadiskattach" {
```

This is how I have my disk, attach disk and snapshot resources defined:

```
// Create additional disks
resource "google_compute_disk" "datadisk" {
  name  = var.data_disk_name
  type  = var.data_disk_type
  size  = var.data_disk_size
  zone  = var.zone
  image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
    asv = "mycompanytools"
    ownercontact = "myuser"
  }
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}

// Attach additional disks
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "datadiskattach" {
  disk = google_compute_disk.datadisk.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}

// Create a snapshot of the datadisk volume
resource "google_compute_snapshot" "datadisksnapshot" {
  name        = var.datadisk_volume_snapshot_name
  source_disk = google_compute_disk.datadisk.name
  zone        = var.zone
  labels = {
    my_label = var.datadisk_volume_snapshot_label
  }
}
```

Here is how I am naming them in the variables. The naming seems to be clashing in the error I got:

```
// Create Data Disk Variables
variable "data_disk_name" {
  description = "Value of the disk name for the data disk for the GCP instance"
  type        = string
  default     = "dev-sql-td-data-disk"
}

// Create Snapshot Variables
variable "datadisk_volume_snapshot_name" {
  description = "Value of the datadisk name for the GCP instance root disk volume"
  type        = string
  default     = "dev-sql-td-data-disk-volume-snapshot"
}
```

How can I get passed this error?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform documentation has suggested that, "When using google_compute_attached_disk you must use lifecycle.ignore_changes = ["attached_disk"] on the google_compute_instance resource that has the disks attached. Otherwise the two resources will fight for control of the attached disk block"
Ref link: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_attached_disk

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is asking for the disk you are taking a snapshot from and not another disk as seen in the error. The source disk must be the boot VM disk and not the additional disk that you are attaching.
For simplicity, I will just add

```html
resource "google_compute_snapshot" "snapshot-backup" {
  name        = "snapshot-name"
  source_disk = "boot-os"
  # zone              = "europe-west3-b"
  storage_locations = ["eu", ]
}
```

[Refer here for more information](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_snapshot)

Comment: Hi @Steve I already provided the link for more information below

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, one can remove the following because `Terraform` will tell you that the resources is already being used.

```
// Attach additional disks
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "datadiskattach" {
    disk = google_compute_disk.datadisk.id
    instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to use proper code formatting.